# Trying to hide Django to JS declared variable displaying in page source

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates

I'm building a RESTful API that renders front-end using Django templating, but where the front-end is essentially built using JS/JQuery.  Right now I'm just checking to see that the data has been sent properly, and I have a very simple template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block body %}
  Click <a href="{% url 'home_view' %}">here</a> to go to the home page
  <hr>
  <div id="keySelectForm"></div>
  <div id="dataDisplay"></div>
{% endblock %}
```

When the page loads I am just adding a simple drop-down box with the relevant data that has been passed to the front-end and a click-box that simply shows said data on the page.  As such, I am declaring JS variables in a script at the bottom of the page as follows:

```
{% block javascript %}
{{ block.super }}
<script id="dataDisplayScript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  var df_dict = {{ df_dict|safe }};
  var names = {{ names|safe }};

  // Build form
  var form = $('<form></form>');
  var selection = $('<select name="keys" id="keySelectBox"></select>');
  var button = $('<button id="test">Click me</button>');
  form.append(selection)
  // Add selection options to main page
  Object.keys(df_dict).forEach(function(key) {
    selection.append($('<option value="' + key + '">' + key + '</option>'));
  });
  form.append(button);
  $('#keySelectForm').append(form);

  // Pull data from select box and display only that part of the JSON
  $('#test').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
   $("#dataDisplay").empty().append(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(df_dict[$('form').serializeArray()[0].value])));
  });
});
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

In order to do this I need to load all of the JSON on page load, but upon declaring the variable "df_dict" the raw data that was passed in context from the back-end as df_dict is visible within the dev tools.  Since I need to use the {{ }} notation to access the data I can't simply move this script to an external file and **I'm wondering if there is a way to hide this data so it is not visible within the page source** ("Elements" in Chrome dev tools).  As you can see, I've tried assigning an ID to the script and setting

```
script#dataDisplayScript {
  display: none;
}
```

in CSS to no avail.

Comment: In theory, you could delete the script block entirely after you're done with it `var scriptBlock = document.getElementById('dataDisplayScript'); scriptBlock.parentElement.removeChild(scriptBlock);`. You'd probably have to rework things a little bit to transfer your data to a separate script file before you delete it, though, and do your click binding in that separate file as well.